# What would cause GZipStream compressed data to have excessive padding with zeroes?

Tags: .net, compression, gzipstream

I'm compressing some packets of data using the GZipStream class within the .NET framework. Everything works fine and the compression ratio is OK, but when I peek at the compressed data using a hex editor I noticed that as much as a third of each compressed packet is trailing zeroes. Is this normal?

Presumably GZipStream is a block based compressor and the output is padded to align with some block size? Are there some alternatives that are equally stable, as well supported but without this issue? (I figure I can gain another 10-30% compression by using a similar compression algorithm that doesn't pad so excessively).

Comment: How did you use it? For example using `MemoryStream.GetBuffer` instead of `MemoryStream.ToArray` or a `FileStream` would cause such issues.

Comment: I think that's it. If you want post as an answer I will accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `GZipStream` shouldn't add an excessive amount of trailing zeros.

But if you use [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) incorrectly, it can cause this effect. It internally uses a `byte[]` to store the data. This internal buffer can be larger than the data written so far to reduce the number of allocations. If you use [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) you get back the full array, it's your own responsibility to only use the first `Length` bytes of it.

Alternatively you can call [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) which returns a new byte array with exactly `Length` bytes.

To quote the documentation for `GetBuffer()`:

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused. For example, if the string `"test"` is written into the `MemoryStream` object, the length of the buffer returned from `GetBuffer` is 256, not 4, with 252 bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use the `ToArray` method; however, `ToArray` creates a copy of the data in memory.

Answer (score 2):

The gzip format does not have trailing zeros.  Other than at most three trailing zero bytes for small files, since the length of the uncompressed data (modulo 2<sup>32</sup>) is stored at the end as a four-byte little-endian integer.

Something else is putting those zeros there.